# Keras/Tensorflow installation R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library

My Keras/Tensorflow worked and for a reason I didnot understand, it crashed. I uninstalled everything and re-install again following these next step:

1) Install ANACONDA. 2019.03 X64
2) in Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
pip install --upgrade pillow
conda install -c conda-forge keras tensorflow
pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

3) Install R 3.6.0

4) Install Rstudio 1.2.1335

5) Install Rtools3.5  with "add rtools to syst path"

6) In Rstudio

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
library(keras)
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
```

When I run the Keras model I have the following message:

Error in image_load(idx, target_size = c(64, 64)) : 
  The Pillow Python package is required to load images

***I have Pillow already, so why I have this error ? How to solve it?***

Here some detail:

> tf_config()

```
TensorFlow v1.14.0 (C:\Users\Mezeix\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.p)
```

> reticulate::py_config()

```
python:         C:\Users\Mezeix\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe

libpython:      C:/Users/Mezeix/Anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/python36.dll

pythonhome:     C:\Users\Mezeix\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1

version:        3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Architecture:   64bit

numpy:          C:\Users\Mezeix\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\numpy

numpy_version:  1.16.4

tensorflow:     C:\Users\Mezeix\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.p

python versions found: 
 C:\Users\Mezeix\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe
 C:\Users\Mezeix\ANACON~1\python.exe
 C:\Users\Mezeix\Anaconda3\python.exe

Python v3.6 (C:\Users\Mezeix\Anaconda3\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe)
```

Comment: Did you run `keras::install_keras()`?

Comment: After or before doing  devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras") ?

Comment: From your comment I did it but no change, still  the following message: The Pillow Python package is required to load images

Comment: Can you share the updated output of `reticulate::py_config()`? The `install_keras` is suposed to download an Anaconda environment, named `r-reticulate` or something like that. If you can find that, I think you can uninstall the separate Anaconda installation, unless you use it for your `python` programs. You'll then have to let keras use the reticulate environment, either automatically, or using `reticulate::use_python`.

Comment: Please see my answer in the next message